# Azure python sdk list of OS

Tags: python, azure

I try to get a list of all or most popular operating systems in azure (like ubuntu, centos, windows, etc.) using python sdk, all this to make a new virtual machine, in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-python for make a new virtual machine you need a storage_profile:

```
'storage_profile': {
            'image_reference': {
                'publisher': 'Canonical',
                'offer': 'UbuntuServer',
                'sku': '16.04.0-LTS',
                'version': 'latest'
            },
        },
```

How can i get a list of this storage profiles or image references in python azure sdk? i try to use **azure.mgmt.compute ComputeManagementClient** but no has methods to get a list of storage profiles or image references, 
the official documentation of azure is very confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to get the VM images in the Azure marketplace. For this, you can take a look at the [VirtualMachineImagesOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.operations.virtualmachineimagesoperations?view=azure-python) class, use the methods in it, then you can get the VM images which available with special requirements in the Azure marketplace.

**Update:**

Here is an example that gets the images in the Azure marketplace:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

Subscription_Id = "xxxxxx"
Tenant_Id = "xxxxxx"
Client_Id = "xxxxxx"
Secret = "xxxxxx"

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=Client_Id,
        secret=Secret,
        tenant=Tenant_Id
        )

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, Subscription_Id)
images = compute_client.virtual_machine_images.list_offers('eastus', 'Canonical')
for image in images:
    print(image.name)
```

Comment: I have been working with the class you mentioned but I do not have the parameters and I don't know where to get them, I am very frustrated and azure documentation does not help. I try import just like this: from azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.operations import VirtualMachineImagesOperations  and i pass the compute_client and others args like this: vmio = VirtualMachineImagesOperations(compute_client,{},None,None)

Comment: @AbelOlguinChavez The parameters just like the things that you provide in the question, the publisher, offer and sku. Choose the method and use things of them as the need.

Comment: @AbelOlguinChavez I update the answer to give an example. Hope it helps you.

Comment: that's it! I didn't know that was the publisher parameter, you are the crack, thanks a lot

Comment: @AbelOlguinChavez I'm glad it helps you and you can mark it as the answer.